# Alleles and Ploidy

Tags: genetics, allele, haplodiploid

I was recently studying inheritance and variation and came across a sentence:

> A diploid organism can show only two alleles

How is this possible?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks I got it. Should I need to delete this question. Or leave it as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"In a diploid organism, one that has two copies of each chromosome, two alleles make up the individual's genotype."*

[Source](https://www.sciencedaily.com/terms/allele.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Human is a diploid organism. We have 23 chromosomes. Every body cell has 46 chromosomes, one set of 23 chromosomes from mom another set of 23 chromosomes from dad. There is one chromosome number 1 from dad another chromosome number 1 from mom. Each chromosome contains in average 1000 genes. Each gene encodes a protein. For example half of the hemoglobin (the protein of red blood cells that transports oxygen) is encoded by the gene that you had from your mom, the other half of the hemoglobin is encoded by the gene that you got from your dad. In both cases you are encoding the hemoglobin, but the exact structure of the molecule can be different. These differences are representing the allele. The idea is generalized to all other 20'000 genes of the human genome encoding other proteins (such as insulin, hair, skin, retina proteins).

There are slight exceptions to everything I said which you can ignore at this stage (for example some cells do not have chromosomes, because they destroy them, and reproductive cells have only 23 chromosomes instead of 46).

Hope that this helps